# how to set minimum hours in timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker, bootstrap-timepicker

hi i have one issue with timepicker 
i am working with create multiple timepicker using jquery now 
i want like

> i want if i select 01:00 to then in next timepicker will start after 01 so for next timepicker user only able to add time after 01 also 01 not display in timepicker

i try this code

```
jQuery('.timepicker2').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    showMeridian: false,
    maxHours: 20,
    minHours: 2,
});
```

please help me for this issue

Comment: Is it bootstrap timepicker or jquery timepicker?

Comment: bootstrap timepicker

Comment: There are quite a few libraries out there for bootstrap timepicker. Ideally you should check whether the library you are using supports this feature on their github repo. At least, include the link to the repo in the question, and if possible, include your working code as a snippet in the question.

Comment: Try hourMin and hourMax but as the others have suggested it depends on the library you are using....